# Browser-sync doesn't save scroll position when refresh browser page

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

Page scrolls up after changes (include changes in css).
After css changes I see notification "Injected: style.css".
Used Firefox, Gulp 3.9.1, and Browser-sync 2.18.13.

```
const gulp         = require('gulp');
const browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('server', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'build/',
    },
    open: false,
    online: false,

    files:[  
        'build/*.html',
        'build/css',
        'build/js',
        'build/fonts/',
        'build/img',
    ],

    ghostMode: {
        scroll: true
    },

    logLevel: 'info', // 'debug', 'info', 'silent', 'warn'
    logConnections: false,
    logPrefix: "Browser-Sync",
    port: 8080,
    notify: true
  });
});
```

Comment: ghostMode scroll:true is the default.  It only synchronizes the scroll positon between open devices or browsers - I don't think it has anything to do with the scroll position on a reload.  So it is more of a question of how you ae reloading; you should show your sass/css task or how you call browserSync.reload preferably with {stream:true} option.